# C++ Code to Connect to Oracle DB Not Working

Tags: c++, database-connection

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB using Visual Studio 2022, programming language C++. I have all the include directories specified in my project properties, as well as all relevant .lib files linked. Here is my code (note that I entered my actual username, password, and connect string in my code):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<occi.h>
    #include<oci.h>
    #include<ociextp.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace oracle::occi;



    int main()
    {

       Environment* env = nullptr;
       Connection* conn= nullptr;

        try {
            env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
            conn = env->createConnection("username", "password", "connectstring");

            if (conn) {
                cout << " Connection sucessful" << endl;
         
            }
            else {
                cout << "Connection failed" <<endl;
            }


        }
        catch (SQLException& e) {
            cout << "Connection failed. Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        }
        Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

 
        return 0;   

    }
```

I keep getting the same output stating "connection failed. Error: " with no error code.

When I use the debugger, I get this message, not sure if it is relevant:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help

I tried Googling my issue and asking ChatGPT to get some direction, but I haven't found anything similar to my problem. I am hoping to get my code to output "connection successful"

EDIT: I continue to get Connection Failed. in my output but now I am getting error code 32104

Comment: Interesting. CCCCCCCC usually means [uninitialized stack memory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) I don't see how you could possibly get that with `Environment* env = nullptr;` unless you have two `env`s floating around.

Comment: I recommend at least two `try` blocks, one for environment, the other for connection.  This will give more detailed error messages.